# An $\operatorname{erfi}(x)e^{-x^2}$ integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I want to find an elementary evaluation of

> $$I=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erfi}(x)e^{-x^2}-\frac1{1+2x}\right)dx$$
>   where $\operatorname{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$.

**Rough Solution**
$$I=\int_0^\infty\left({}_1F_1(1;3/2,-x^2)x-\frac1{1+2x}\right)dx$$
$$=\left(\frac{x^2}2{}_2F_2(1,1;3/2,2,-x^2)-\frac12\ln(1+2x)\right)\Bigg|_0^\infty$$
By using the asymptotic expansion of $_2F_2$ I can get the answer is $\frac{\gamma}4$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant.
I wonder if there is a elementary proof without using hypergeometric function.

Comment: $erfi(x)$ and $erf(x)$ , which one is yours?  In general $\operatorname{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{z^2}dz,$ and $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-z^2}dz.$

Comment: @Riemann. According to the result, it is $\text{erfi}$

Comment: Probably not useful, but $$I=\int_0^\infty\,\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,\text{erfc}(x)\,\exp\left(+x^2\right)-\frac{1}{1+2x}\right)\,\text{d}x\,.$$  Here, $\text{erfc}(x)=1-\text{erf}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.  (Of course, I assume that $\text{erf}$ and $\text{erfi}$ are defined correctly as Riemann suggested.)

Comment: @KemonoChen Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: It is $\operatorname{erfi}$. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I haven't think it through, but one approach is to use the differentiation-under-the-integral sign trick, something like $I(\lambda):=\int_0^\infty \left[\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\mathrm{erfi}(\lambda x)\exp(-x^2)-\dfrac{f(\lambda,x)}{1+2x}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x$, where $f(\lambda,x)$ interpolates from $f(\lambda=1)=1$ and behaves compatibly with the truncation $\frac{\mathrm{erfi}(x)}{\mathrm{erfi}(\lambda x)}\sim \lambda^{-1}\exp(-(1-\lambda^2)x^2)$ for large $x$, perhaps $\dfrac{f(\lambda,x)}{(1+2x)}=\dfrac{\exp(-(1-\lambda^2)x^2)}{1+2x+(1-\lambda)x^2}$ or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}I&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a\left(e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2}~dt-\frac{1}{1+2x}\right)dx\\\color{gray}{[t=xy]}&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_0^a\!\!\int_0^1 xe^{-x^2(1-y^2)}~dy~dx-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+2a)\right)\\\color{gray}{[\text{int. over }x]}&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{-a^2(1-y^2)}}{2(1-y^2)}~dy-\frac{\ln2a}{2}\right)\\\color{gray}{[\text{int. by parts}]}&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^1ye^{-a^2(1-y^2)}\ln\frac{1+y}{1-y}~dy-\frac{\ln2a}{2}\right)\\\color{gray}{[a^2(1-y^2)=z]}&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{a^2}e^{-z}\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z/a^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-z/a^2}}~dz-\frac{\ln2a}{2}\right)\end{align} and, using $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-z/a^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-z/a^2}}=\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{1-z/a^2})^2}{z/a^2}$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-z}\ln z~dz=-\gamma$, we get indeed $$I=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^{a^2}e^{-z}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-z/a^2}\right)~dz+\frac{\gamma}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\color{blue}{=\frac{\gamma}{4}}.$$